# 2operating systems on same desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

"After your computer restarts, choose 'Ubuntu' from the boot menu."

is it possible to choose between ubuntu and windows each time the desktop is started up ?

Comment: by same desktop do you mean the same PC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do this.  If you install Ubuntu from a live disk or live USB, it will ask you if you want to erase windows or install alongside.  If you select install alongside every time you turn on your computer it will ask you to boot either Ubuntu or Windows.

[image]